# When is it true that $K \cap F(a) = F$ and $[K(a):F(a)] = [K:F]$?

Tags: galois-theory, separable-extension, normal-extension

This is a follow-up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3604659/a-generalization-of-the-theorem-on-natural-irrationalities) question, where I am attempting to solve problem 5.26 of Morandis *Field and Galois Theory.*

Let $K/F$ be a normal extension, and let $E \supseteq K$ be some larger field, with $a \in E - K$ separable (and algebraic) over $F$. First of all, is it true that $K \cap F(a) = F$? And if so, is it then true that $[K(a):F(a)] = [K:F]$? My intuition tells me that this is too good to be true, but I can't find a counter-example.

Something that might help is that none of the roots of $\min(F,a)$ are in $K$.  If one of them is, then $\min(F,a)$ splits over $K$, implying that $a \in K$, contrary to our assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that $K\cap F(a)=F$. For a counterexample, take an element $b\in K-F$ that is not a square in $K$ and let $a\in E$ be such that $a^2=b$. Then
$$F\subsetneq F(b)\subset K\cap F(a).$$

Comment: How can you ensure that $a$ is separable over $F$?

Comment: You can always take $F$ perfect. But $\operatorname{char}F\neq2$ is sufficient here, as the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$ is $X^2-b=(X-a)(X+a)$.